# Prevent external devices being locked to launcher

Tags: 14.04, usb, android, mtp

If I connect an external device (such as a USB stick or android smartphone) it will automatically open in nautilus and get a corresponding icon locked to unity launcher. Is there any way to prevent this?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You should be able to just right click the drive in the launcher and choose to un-pin or unlock it.

Comment: Yea I can remove it (even while connected) but the next time i plug it in it will be back.

Comment: hmm. Check Nautilus' preferences

Comment: would you find a tiny background script an acceptable solution?

Comment: Sorry Zacharee1 I cant find any preference setting related to this.
Jacob Vlijm ill accept any solution :)

Comment: Hi @amoz871 did you notice the answer? Please let me know if you manage.

Comment: Yes I just saw it. Didn't have access to my computer all evening yesterday but marked as accepted answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you unlock a device from the Unity Launcher, it as actually *blacklisted* from the launcher. You can see which devices are currently blacklisted by the command:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```

The script below is an alternative way to set your own *blacklisted devices*. The difference is that the script does it in a permanent way, untill you remove the file `~/.blacklist_data`. (see explanation: *How it works*)

#### background script

Even for a background script, this one is *extremely* light weight, as a result of the fact that, if nothing changes to the blacklist, only the current blacklist is read by the `gsettings` command. It reads the `dconf` database, which is in `binary` format, and thus very light weight.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time

blacklist_data = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.blacklist_data"

def get_setlist():
    cmd = "gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist"
    blacklist = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    return "[]" if blacklist == "@as []" else blacklist

try:
    blacklist1 = str(open(blacklist_data).read()).strip()
    cmd = 'gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "'+blacklist1+'"'
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
except FileNotFoundError:
    blacklist1 = "[]"
    open(blacklist_data, "wt").write(blacklist1)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    blacklist2 = get_setlist()
    if blacklist2 != blacklist1:
        oldlist = open(blacklist_data).read().strip()
        n_old = len(eval(oldlist))
        try:
            n_new = len(eval(blacklist2))
        except SyntaxError:
            n_new = 0
        if n_old < n_new:
            open(blacklist_data, "wt").write(blacklist2)
        else:
            cmd = 'gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist "'+oldlist+'"'
            subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
    blacklist1 = blacklist2
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `myown_blacklist.py`
2. Test- run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /pat/to/myown_blacklist.py`
   ```

   Now unlock your (any, it works not only usb devices) unwanted devices. Unlocking is only needed once.
3. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications:  choose Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /pat/to/myown_blacklist.py`
   ```

#### How it works

The issue is that Unity "forgets" devices once they are unmounted. The script then keeps track of what happens to the output of:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist
```

If an item is added to the list, the script writes the list into a hidden file in your home directory. If an item is removed, it reads the hidden file and restores the blacklist (this is only needed once on unmounting of the device)

Comment: @amoz871 Perfect! glad it works :)