# Disable automatic shortcut creation for network mounts

Tags: 16.04, mount, launcher, pcmanfm, places

I just wrote a script that searches for every samba device in a network and mounts all shares it can find on those devices. 
It works just fine, but my launcher sidebar became quite unusable.
I know I could manually unlock them all, but I don't want to do that every time I update the shares.

I also find it quite annoying that my file explorer (`pcmanfm`) displays every mounted share in its own sidebar under `places`. I couldn't find an option to remove them.

How can I disable the automatic creation of all those shortcuts?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't have nautilus.

[image]

Comment: Could be done, but would disabling adding *any* device do, or do we need to be more subtle?

Comment: Anyway, I will post late tonight or tomorrow if no one posted a solution yet.

Comment: I was searching about it and found how to do it selectively [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722911/prevent-external-devices-being-locked-to-launcher#answer-722976)  by @JacobVlijm itself, is it still valid for 16.04? :)

Comment: @M.Becerra it was even written on 16.04, but looking at the amount of devices, it will take an hour to blacklist them all manually :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Well, manually blacklisting really isn't an option here. First of all we are probably talking about 500+ shares. And secondly the shares may change at any time and I really don't want to manually do something every time a new share is created.

Comment: The funny thing is, my samba shares do not appear in the launcher. Could you mention if there is a change in output of `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` after the devices appear in the launcher? Trying to find out what entry to kick.

Comment: The list is pretty short.  Not sure what `'unity://expo-icon'` and `'unity://running-apps'` is. But `'unity://devices'` is probably responsible for all the smb shares showing up. Is there a safe way to remove it?